# Apply manual image cropping not to thumbnail but medium_large size

Tags: images, thumbnails, cropping

When cropping an image in wordpress you can apply the changes to all image sizes at once, the thumbnail (150 x 150) or all sizes except thumbnail. I would like to be able to select other image sizes as well, such as medium or medium_large. Does anyone have an idea how to apply image cropping "only" to a specific image size except thumbnail?

Comment: Why not just add a new image size with cropping?

Comment: @Abhik How can I add a new image size when cropping an image? I think I can either scale or crop an image?

Comment: Here you go.. [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).